# Comprobar campos y detener el envio de formulario

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

tengo un formulario que comprueba el valor de dos textbox, si son diferentes muestra el mensaje que debe arreglarse uno de los campos, pero aun así me envía la información cumpliendose otra clase, aquí mi código:

Este es el que compara los dos textbox:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function comprobarClave(){ 
   bl = document.getElementById('bl').value;
   bl2 = document.getElementById('bl2').value;
  if (bl != bl2){
     alert("Compruebe la informcación de carga.") 
     return false;
  }else{
      
      return true;
   }
}
</script>
```

Y este es el que envía la info; lo que quiero es que no envie los datos si los dos textbox tienen info diferente.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.guardar').submit(function(){
 var x = confirm("¿Estás seguro que quieres guardar?");
      if (x){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "caso2.php",
          data:$(this).serialize(),
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {
                //$('#result').show(3000);
    
    $('#result2').html(data).
            fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();

            }
        });//end ajax
  return false;
      }
      
    });
});
```

```html
<form class="guardar"  id="cass" name="cass"  method="post"  onSubmit = "return comprobarClave(); " autocomplete="off" name="caso"><table width="1151" height="155" border="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
      
        <td><div id="result2"></div>
        BL/BOOKING:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><label for="bl"></label>
          <input type="text" name="bl" id="bl" required="required" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>BL/BOOKING:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><label for="bl2">
          <input type="text" name="bl2" id="bl2" required="required" />
        </label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Fecha:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><label for="fech">
         <?php date_default_timezone_set("America/Bogota"); ?>
          <input type="text" name="fech" id="fech" value="  <?php echo $hoy = date("d/m/y");  ?>" required="required" readonly="readonly" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Nombre del cliente:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><select name="nom_cli" id="nom_cli">    
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root', 'master3.1416');
            mysql_select_db('roda', $con);
        
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cliente ORDER BY nom_cli " ,$con);
              
            $contar = @mysql_num_rows($sql);
              
            if($contar == 0){
           
            }else{
              while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $id_cli = $row['id_cli'];
   
?>
    <option value='<?php echo $nombre = $row["nom_cli"]; ?>' required> <?php echo $nombre = $row["nom_cli"]; ?>  </option>
   <?php  
    }
   }
  ?> 
</select></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Codigo del cliente:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><select name="cod_cli" id="cod_cli" required>    
    <option value='<?php echo $cod_cli = $row["cod_cli"]; ?>' name='cod_cli' id='cod_cli' required>   </option>
</select></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Origen:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><label for="Origen">
          <input type="text" name="origen" id="origen" required="required" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cantidad de items/cont:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><label for="cant"></label>
          <input type="number" name="cant" id="cant" min="1"/>      <label for="nom_cli"></label></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Almacenamiento:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><label for="alm"></label>
          <input type="date" name="alm" id="alm" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Retención:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><label for="ret"></label>
          <input type="date" name="ret" id="ret" /></td>
        </tr>
      
      </table>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="send"  value="Guardar"    />
        <button type="reset" class="button" value="Limpiar">Reset</button>
      </p>
  </form>
```

Y este es mi form.

Answer (score 1):

Para que ejecutas dos veces el evento submit ? Solo deberías hacerlo una vez, además si estas usando jQuery para que usas JavaScript nativo ?

Cambia tu línea de form por esto:

```
<form class="guardar" id="cass" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

Y tu js:

```
$('.guardar').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var bl = $("#bl").val();
    var bl2 = $("#bl2").val();

    if (bl != bl2){
        alert("Compruebe la informcación de carga.") 
    }else{
        var x = confirm("¿Estás seguro que quieres guardar?");
        if (x){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "caso2.php",
                data:$(this).serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    //$('#result').show(3000);
                    $('#result2').html(data).
                    fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                }
            });//end ajax
        } 
    }    
});
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: es que soy  soy un roockie en la programación, por cierto, no me funcionó :)

Comment: Ok, vamos a debuggear, dime cual fue el comportamiento y revisa la consola a ver si se imprimió algún error

Comment: se resetio el form, como si se hubiese actualizado la pagina.

Comment: Lo acabo de probar en mi pc y funciona, seguro que estás probando bien ? Mientras probaba encontré mas errores: cambia esto `value="  <?php echo $hoy = date("d/m/y");  ?>"` por esto: `value="  <?php echo $hoy = date('d/m/y');  ?>"` adicional revisa bien tus `required`, los `required` van en los `select` y en los `input` y tienes algunos en la etiqueta `option`

Answer (score 1):

Te envía la información por que estas usando el evento submit en esta línea de código:

**< input type="submit" class="button" name="send"  value="Guardar"    />**

Cambia el type="submit" por **type="button"** en tu formulario. Además agrega el valor "guardar" al atributo class para que quede de la siguiente forma: **class="button guardar"**